# Pandas - How do I look for a set of values in a column and if it is present return a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I have a csv file which has a latitude and longitude columns and also a tile ID column, the file has around 1 million rows. I have a list of around a hundred tile ID's and want to get the latitude and longitude coordinates for these tile ID's. Currently I have:

```
good_tiles_str = [str(q) for q in good_tiles]#setting list elements to string data type
file['tile'] = file.tile.astype(str)#setting title column to string data type

for i in range (len(good_tiles_str)):
     x = good_tiles_str[i]
     lat = file.loc[file['tile'].str.contains(x), 'BL_Latitude'] #finding lat coordinates
     long = file.loc[file['tile'].str.contains(x), 'BL_Longitude'] #finding long coordinates
print(lat)
print(long)
```

This method is very slow and I know it is not the correct way as I heard you should not use for loops like this whilst using pandas. Also, it does not work as it doesn't find all the latitude and longitude points for the tile ID's

Any help would be very gladly appreciated

Comment: Can you produce a [MCVE]?

Comment: try this: `df = file[file['tile'].isin(good_tiles_str)]` this will give you df, next steps are super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
search_for = '|'.join(good_tiles_str)
good = file[file.tile.str.contains(search_for)]
good = good[['BL_Latitude', 'BL_Longitude']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Instead of join and creating a mask, you can use `isin` as in `file[file.title.isin(search_for)]`

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't `isin` look for the whole string, not substrings?

Comment: search_for is a list. so isin matches for the string the list of strings. I didn't get an impression that search_for contains substrings

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]`. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The code runs but it returns too many latitude and longitude coordinates. The list good_tiles_str only has 698 elements and i get 124580 latitude and longitude coordinates

Comment: @Harry Maguire, Try it now.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work Thank you very much. Do you know any sources where i could find more about these kinds of issues? Also is good a series or list?

Comment: Does '|' just split the list up ?

Comment: `good` is a dataframe, just like `file`. `"|".join` basically creates a string like `apple|ball|cat|dog` etc. This is used to filter the dataframe. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate rows explicitly , I think as far as I understood your question.

If you wish a particular assignment given a condition, you can do so explicitly. Here's one way using numpy.where; we use ~ to indicate "negative".

```
rule1= file['tile'].str.contains(x)
rule2= file['tile'].str.contains(x)

file['flag'] = np.where(rule1 , 'BL_Latitude', " " )
file['flag'] = np.where(rule2 & ~rule1, 'BL_Longitude', file['flag'])
```

Comment: this is too complicated. ashish's is more readable and Pandas(ic)

Comment: I have tried the code and it does not work currently, im not sure what 'flag' is referring to. I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Its just passing if else condition in np.where and flagging the result withan additional column. numpy.where(condition[, x, y])                                                                  
Thats it :-)

Comment: @HarryMaguire : Its 'tile Id " column in your case. Please try now

Comment: @HarryMaguire : It will help if you can send the code in which you are getting error.

Comment: Thankyou I have tried the solution below and it seems to work Im just about to ask how his code actually works

Comment: @HarryMaguire : It will check the rule1 first and where ever the rule1 satisfiy , it will tag it as 'BL_Latitude' in the additional  column and wherever the rule doesn't satisfy it will leave the column blank. Then it it will read the rule 2 excluding rule1 and wherever it satisfies it will write 'BL_Longitude' in the column , otherwise it will leave the values written already based on rule1 as it is without overwriting it.